# Python Selenium chromedriver OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error

Tags: python, macos, selenium

I'm trying to set up a chrome session with Selenium in my python (2.7) script like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "soup_test.py", line 30, in <module>
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 62, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Searching through other questions a common issue seems to be that chromedriver is not on the path, but I checked and it is. I even tried specifying the path explicitly:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome("/path/to/chromedriver")
```

with the same result. Anyone know what could be the problem? I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: I'd also like to know..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem by uninstalling all instances of chromedriver (I had multiple in different locations) and then installing it again with homebrew: `brew install chromedriver`

Comment: On osx once you do `brew install chromedriver` you should be able to point `executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`