# Automation in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework, geckodriver, selenium2library

I have written a simple test case to open Firefox browser and go to "https://www.google.co.in". I am getting this error.

[image]

Test script

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***  
case1
        Open Browser    https://www.google.co.in/    ff
```

Comment: Share your test script to have better understanding

Comment: @Rakesh I have updated it. Please check

Comment: Could you please post the error in text? Try to avoid using images for errors / code.

Comment: Can you provide details on your OS, Python, Robot Framework and Selenium(2)Library versions? In addition, have you tried with the more recent  SeleniumLibrary?

Answer (score 2):

To Run in Firefox we need geckodriver. Place geckodriver in `C:/python/scripts` and then try to run the scripts.
To Run in Chrome, place chrome driver X32 in `C:/python/scripts` and then run your scrpts

Comment: By the looks of it (the screenshot), @Ishanmahajan is using linux, don't put it in c:\ :). Get the latest version of (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), andadd it to the system path (`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver`); the gents at FF are recommedning the latest selenium, so make sure you're up to date. Also make sure firefox binary is in the path.

Comment: yup i am using ubuntu 16.04. I have put them in /usr/local/bin. Selenium and firefox are upto date.

Answer (score 1):

you need download driver firefox  first

[Download Here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)

Answer (score 0):

Searching for the error: "[Selenium OSerror [Errno 8] firefox](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Selenium%20OSerror%20[Errno%208]%20firefox&*)" in Google the first few results were quite informative and it seems to me that this was not done.

The first few options highlight that not the correct webdriver is installed. Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833589/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-selenium). (A different error is presented when the Gecko driver is not installed).

In a follow-up [result item](https://www.solved.tips/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error/) an explanation was given that the script is missing a shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` when a script is fired.

Comment: Most of the links relate to chrome driver not firefox. Well I degrade my firefox version and selenium version and this was solved.

Comment: For the help of others, can you write an answer in which you explain what you did to solve your issue. I.e. from which version you downgraded from and to so that others can benefit from it?

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser version and browser operation system(32 bit or 64 bit) then install the driver put inside python installation directory.
For Example :
C:\Python27/yourinstalleddriver.exe 
either 
C:\Python27\Scripts/yourinstalleddriver.exe

Answer (score 0):

Most of the links relate to chrome driver not firefox. Well I degrade my firefox version and selenium version and this was solved.