# Unable to run Selenium + Python Script on linux mint with Chrome and firefox

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, linux-mint

I am not able to run/execute **python(3.5)**+**selenium(3.4.0)** script on **Linux Mint 18.1 Serena** using on **Chrome** and  **Firefox**.

Details:

When I try to run below script for Chrome or Firefox browser I am facing issues, It runs perfectly fine on windows machine but giving some weird issues on Linux Mint.

Chrome:-

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
driver.close()
```

Result:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample1.py", line 6, in <module>
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py3.5.egg /selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 261, in get
self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py3.5.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 247, in execute
response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py3.5.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py3.5.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 488, in _request
resp = self._conn.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

FireFox :-

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
driver.close()
```

Result:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample1.py", line 4, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py3.5.egg/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 142, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/selenium-3.4.0-py3.5.egg/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 74, in start
stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Comment: Have you got geckodriver and/or chrome driver installed?

Comment: Yes @GenericSnake geckodriver and chromedriver both installed and added to system PATH

Comment: Are you using the latest versions of chrome/firefox? I know firefox updated recently, so that may be affecting it: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43665289/unable-to-run-selenium-python-script-on-linux-mint-with-chrome-and-firefox?noredirect=1#comment74378071_43665289  Although it seems you have two different errors which is confusing...

Comment: Yes @GenericSnake
Firefox and Chrome both updated, I tried on older version of Firefox but I am observing same issues

Answer (score 3):

I resolved issue by changing permissions of geckodriver and move geckodriver under /usr/local/bin

```
chmod +x geckodriver
cp geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

I think so it will work same for chromedriver
Thanks for all help guys

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so having a look around, it seems that this a complaint about the binaries you're using for at least geckodriver. As seen here [OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833589/oserror-errno-8-exec-format-error-selenium)

You should check the geckodriver/chromedrive you set the paths for, and make sure that the binaries you're using aren't for the windows version (which i suspect is the reason why it works for windows and not for linux mint - assuming you're sharing the machine)

I'm hoping that helps you. :) (I must admit though, I'm not quite sure why the errors are totally different for both browsers)

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be Pycharm. It works fine if I run from terminal. Could be a permission issue from Pycharm.